# dgrid onDemandGrid renders larger than the space it's in, therefore causing vertical scrolling

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I'm trying to render the dgrid without the vertical scrollbar showing up, but for some reason, it always renders larger than the space it's in.

When the grid loads, it renders at 400x300 even though the space is only 300x200 which then causes vertical scrolling. How do I prevent that?

```js
addGrid: function () {
                this.grid = (declare([OnDemandGrid, Selection]))({
                    id: "tgrid" + this.reportId,
                    loadingMessage: 'Loading data...',
                    noDataMessage: 'No results found.',
                    allowTextSelection: true,
                    scroller: true,
                    collection: new Memory({
                        idProperty: "id"
                    }),
                    columns: {
                        trackName: "Name",
                        urn: {
                            label: "URN",
                            renderCell: function(object, value, cell) {
                                if(typeof value === 'undefined' ) {
                                    cell.bgColor = "red";
                                } else {
                                    cell.innerHTML = value;
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        location: "Location",
                        affiliation: "Affiliation",
                        eta: "ETA",
                        lta: "LTA"
                    }
                }, this.gridId);
                //next get the tracks using this call
                this.getTracks();
            }
```

```css
.dgrid {
    height: auto;
}

.dgrid-row {
    padding: 3px 0 2px 9px;
}

.dgrid-scroller {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 95%;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the dgrid and claro css files? If so, can you point to an example (maybe a fiddle) where this is happening?

Comment: Yes, as well as a few others. Unfortunately, there are too many moving parts to post on fiddle. <link rel="stylesheet" href="${dojoContextRoot}/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${dojoContextRoot}/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${dojoContextRoot}/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${dojoContextRoot}/dojox/widget/Toaster/Toaster.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${dojoContextRoot}/dojox/layout/resources/ExpandoPane.css"/>

Comment: Why add dojox grid's CSS to a dgrid example?  See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devpaul/3bxsxpvm/) for a possible starting point to create a runnable dgrid example.  (If you're using 0.4, update dgrid's version and add dstore to `packages`.)